# How can I make 5 mod 5 = 5 instead of zero?

Tags: javascript, modulo

I'm making a program that uses mod 5.

So I divide the input numbers by five and return the remainder.

```
var mod5 = function (xx) {
     var mod = 5;
     return ((xx % 5) + 5) % 5;
}
```

thus `6 = 1`, `4 = 4`, and `8 = 3`.

By following this rule all things divisible by `5 = 0`,

In order for my program to work, `5, 10, 15, 20 ... mod 5`, all must = `5` instead of `0`.

But all other numbers need to remain the same. What is the easiest way to do this?

P.S. I'm extremely new to programming and I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try (xx % 5) || 5

Comment: If the result is zero just add 5? Your requirement is weird, since `5 % 5` is factually `0`.

Comment: I think your question is good but you shouldn't name your function mod because it technically isn't mod. `5 % 5` has to be zero.

Comment: @pointy I know my requirement is weird but its the only way that will work.

Comment: I see you got your answer but I just want to point out in your code that `((xx % 5) + 5) % 5` is actually the same thing as `xx % 5`

Comment: @Kodos johnson realized that myself but felt like changing the question might confuse people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var mod5 = function (xx) {
  return (xx % 5) || 5
}
```

This function will return `xx mod 5` if it is different of zero, otherwise it will return 5, more explained:

`xx % 5` will result in any number between -4 and 4 `-4 <= xx % 5 <= 4`, then, an [OR logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) compares that result with the number five, the OR logical operator works as the following:

If the value in the left side of the operator is `true`, or [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it will be returned independently of the value in the right side.

If the value in the right side is `true`, or truthy, AND the value in the left side is `false`, or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will be returned.

Orherwise, in case none of the value is `true` or truthy, `false` will be returned.

In this case, `xx % 5` will be returned only if `xx` is not multiple of 5, otherwise, 5 will be returned.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: SImple and elegant, but you should explain why it works.

Comment: @Paul will do :) give me a second

Comment: @Paul there you go :)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
function mod5(x) {
  var result = x % 5; 
  if (result === 0) return 5;
  return result;
}
```

Per your requirements, anything that is divisible by 5 will yield 5.  Everything else is unchanged.

Comment: @Lucero Why wouldn't it? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mod5 = function (xx) {
    var mod = xx % 5;
    if(mod == 0) 
        return 5;
    else 
        return mod;
}
```

Seems simple, if it's modulus 5 is 0, then just return 5.

Comment: `else` is redundant and you're not using `mod`.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that if it's modulus by 5, then return 5, `but all other numbers need to remain the same`. If the requirement was to return the number as is, then yes you're right. But I don't see that in the code at all.

Comment: Not sure what you're on about tbh. The answer with +4 votes is doing exactly the same thing I am. But oh well.

Comment: Minor nitpick but I don't see the point of doing mod two times.

Comment: well... the redundant `else` statement and redudant variable`var mod = 5;`. And the code doesn't do the same thing, it may resolve `xx % 5` twice.

Comment: @KodosJohnson touche.

Answer (score 0):

Made the assumption that if 0 was passed in, you'd want 0 to come back instead of 5.

```
var mod5 = function(xx) {
    var mod = 5;
    if (!xx)
        return 0;
    if (xx % mod === 0)
        return mod;
    return xx % mod;
}
```

Comment: @George - Yep, but in order to still return 0 when xx === 0, you have to handle that case.  If you passed 0 into all of the previous solutions, you'd get 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mod_positive = var(xx, yy = 5){
    return ((xx - 1) %% yy) + 1;
}
```

This question is a repeat of this:
[How can I modulo when my numbers start from 1, not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803331/how-can-i-modulo-when-my-numbers-start-from-1-not-zero)