# Modulus operator c# example

Tags: c#, modulo

Can anyone tell me how to avoid "day 0" without adding new syntax etc.?
In the following example, if the prisoner gets out on Sunday the output is "0" because 7 % 7 is = 0

***clarification: 1-7 represent days of week, if prisoner enters prison on day 2 and stays there for 3 days, he will leave on day 5.
But if prisoner enters on day 3 and stays for 4 days, with this code he will not leave on the 7 but on day 0.
I understand the reason for that (modulo 7 = 0) and I was wondering if you guys have any creative (but with avoiding new syntax) to solve this***

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter day of prison entry (from 1-7)");
    int dayOfEntry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("How many days of sentencing?");
    int daysOfSentencing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    int dayOfRelease = (dayOfEntry + daysOfSentencing) % 7;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Prisoner is due to be released from prison on the: {0} day", dayOfRelease );
```

Comment: Won't work, I want the "0" to be 7.

Comment: `(dayOfEntry + daysOfSentencing - 1) % 7 + 1` maybe?

Comment: You're never going to get `7` as a result of `x % 7`, because you can't have a division remainder equal to the divisor (7). `0` as a result means that whatever you are dividing divides perfectly into 7.

Comment: _"how to avoid "day 0" without adding new syntax etc.?"_-- what does that mean? What makes you think the code _could_ be fixed without "adding new syntax etc.", i.e. introducing some additional code to the code you already have? Taking the question literally, it seems like if you just subtract 1, perform the remainder operation, then add 1, you'll get what you want. But that requires modifying the code. What is it you're actually asking here?

Comment: Please, post sample inputs and desired outputs, because I have no ideia what are you trying to acomplish. Your current code seems to get the day of the week of the release. Is that what you wish for?

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803331/how-can-i-modulo-when-my-numbers-start-from-1-not-zero

Comment: By the way, there's a `DayOfWeek` enumerated type included in the framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek) - where Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6.  You can also use `Enum.Parse` or, better, `Enum.TryParse` to parse text like `"Tuesday"` into `DayOfWeek.Tuesday` which has an integer value of `2` associated with it. Calling `ToString` on an enum, converts it back to a string.  It would make your program easier to understand (code and UI)

Comment: You also probably want to use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`.  Users mess up data entry all the time.  It's better to be able to tell them to try again than to have the program explode in there faces (by throwing an uncaught exception)

Comment: You could recognise that you're the author of your own misfortune here and choose to represent days as the range 0-6 rather than 1-7 and face far fewer difficulties with this logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modulo when my numbers start from 1, not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803331/how-can-i-modulo-when-my-numbers-start-from-1-not-zero)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modulo when my numbers start from 1, not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803331/how-can-i-modulo-when-my-numbers-start-from-1-not-zero)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Often in C# we model real world collections (that are usually 1-based) using a 0-based index. The advantage of C#'s 0-based array indexing is that it plays really nicely into common range logic and modulus operations.

> A really good example for your use case is the [System.DayOfWeek Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-5.0), which has zero set as Sunday. Although your requirement does not need to know or display the name of the day of week, the enum is an example of the .Net standard where having a zero based index is universally accepted across the framework.

To take advantage of this, all we need to do is transpose the user's input by subtracting 1 before performing any range or modulus logic, then add 1 back to the result before presenting back to the user:

The only change you *need* is in this line:

```
int dayOfRelease = ((dayOfEntry + daysOfSentencing - 1) % 7) + 1;
```

We can break that down into discrete steps:

```
// start with the day of entry
var zeroBasedDayOfRelease = dayOfEntry - 1;
// add the days
zeroBasedDayOfRelease += daysOfSentencing;
// apply the modulo
zeroBasedDayOfRelease = zeroBasedDayOfRelease % 7;
int dayOfRelease = zeroBasedDayOfRelease + 1;
```

> This is covered in the answer to [How can I modulo when my numbers start from 1, not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803420/1690217)

We can use the DayOfWeek enum to give more value to our users, as it stands, 1-7 is ambiguous in many countries and cultures and contexts. A common issue in code is that we may need to know if the first day of the week is a Sunday or Monday?

First, lets use DayOfWeek in its declared form:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Enter day of prison entry (from 1-7, where 1 = {DayOfWeek.Sunday} and 7 = {DayOfWeek.Saturday})");
int dayOfEntryInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DayOfWeek dayOfEntry = (DayOfWeek)(dayOfEntryInput - 1);
Console.WriteLine($"Prisoner entry on day {dayOfEntryInput}: {dayOfEntry}");
Console.WriteLine("How many days of sentencing?");
int daysOfSentencing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DayOfWeek dayOfRelease = (DayOfWeek)((int)(dayOfEntry + daysOfSentencing) % 7);
int dayOfReleaseNumber = (int)dayOfRelease + 1;
Console.WriteLine("Prisoner is due to be released from prison on the: {0} day - {1}", dayOfReleaseNumber, dayOfRelease);
```

Output:

```
Enter day of prison entry (from 1-7, where 1 = Sunday and 7 = Saturday)
> 3
Prisoner entry on day 3: Tuesday
How many days of sentencing?
> 4
Prisoner is due to be released from prison on the: 7 day - Saturday
```

If the first day of the week needs to be Monday, and you want the user to enter 1 for Monday, then we can still use the above logic, with a few twists:

```
DayOfWeek dayOne = DayOfWeek.Monday;
int dayZeroShift = 1 - (int)dayOne; 
Console.WriteLine($"Enter day of prison entry (from 1-7, where 1 = {dayOne} and 7 = {(DayOfWeek)((7-dayZeroShift) % 7)})");
int dayOfEntryInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DayOfWeek dayOfEntry = (DayOfWeek)((dayOfEntryInput - dayZeroShift) % 7);
Console.WriteLine($"Prisoner entry on day {dayOfEntryInput}: {dayOfEntry}");
Console.WriteLine("How many days of sentencing?");
int daysOfSentencing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DayOfWeek dayOfRelease = (DayOfWeek)((int)(dayOfEntry + daysOfSentencing) % 7);
// to convert back, we need mod again, which means we have to do the -1 shift
// also add 7 to the base number to avoid negatives
int dayOfReleaseNumber = ((7 + (int)dayOfRelease + dayZeroShift - 1) % 7)+ 1;
Console.WriteLine("Prisoner is due to be released from prison on the: {0} day - {1}", dayOfReleaseNumber, dayOfRelease);
```

Output:

```
Enter day of prison entry (from 1-7, where 1 = Monday and 7 = Sunday)
> 1
Prisoner entry on day 1: Monday
How many days of sentencing?
> 6
Prisoner is due to be released from prison on the: 7 day - Sunday
```

> In this final solution, you could change the `dayOne` to `DayOfWeek.Wednesday` and the logic would still evaluate the correct output days.

Comment: Thanks a lot! not only did you answer my question with a lot of added value, but you also  showed here how thorough one can be in helping an aspiring programmer. Thanks again bro!